# Api is not hitting using react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

user.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { fetchBlog } from '../../redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const Home = ({ blogData, fetchBlog }) => {
const { id } = useParams();
useEffect(() => {
    fetchBlog();
}, []);

return (
    <>
        <div className="container">
            <div className="col-lg-10">
                <h2> React CRUD Operation </h2>
            </div>
            <div className="col-lg-2">
                <Link to="/add" >
                    <button> Add Blog </button>
                </Link>
            </div>
            <table className="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Picture</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Short Description</th>
                        <th>Author</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {blogData.map((it) => {
                        return (
                            <tr key={it.id}>
                                <td> {it.id} </td>
                                <td> {<img src={it.pic} alt="not available" />} </td>
                                <td> {it.title} </td>
                                <td> {it.short_desc} </td>
                                <td> {it.author} </td>

                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
           
    </>
 )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
 return {
  blogData: state.blog
 }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
 return {
    fetchBlog: () => dispatch(fetchBlog())
 }
}

 export default connect (
   mapStateToProps,
   mapDispatchToProps
 ) (Home)
```

userAction.js
import axios from 'axios'

```
export const fetchBlog = () => {
return (dispatch) => {
dispatch(fetchBlogRequest())
axios
  .get('http://localhost:3001/api/blog/get')
  .then(response => {
    const blog = response.data
    dispatch(fetchBlogSuccess(blog))
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // error.message is the error message
    dispatch(fetchBlogFailure(error.message))
  })
  }
 }

export const fetchBlogRequest = () => {
 return {
  type: 'FETCH_BLOGS_REQUEST'
 }
}

 export const fetchBlogSuccess = blogs => {
  return {
   type: 'FETCH_BLOGS_SUCCESS',
   payload: blogs
  }
 }

 export const fetchBlogFailure = error => {
  return {
    type: 'FETCH_BLOGS_FAILURE',
    payload: error
   }
  }
```

user reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
 loading: false,
 blogs: [],
 error: ''
}

const BlogsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_BLOGS_REQUEST':
        return {
            ...state,
            loading: true
        }
    case 'FETCH_BLOGS_SUCCESS':
        return {
            loading: false,
            blogs: action.payload,
            error: ''
        }
    case 'FETCH_BLOGS_FAILURE':
        return {
            loading: false,
            blogs: [],
            error: action.payload
        }
    default: return state
 }
}

export default BlogsReducer
```

rootReducer.js

```
  import  { combineReducers } from 'redux'
  import BlogReducer from './reducer/blog'

 const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  blog: BlogReducer
 });

 export default rootReducer
```

store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './rootReducer'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const store = createStore(
 rootReducer,
 applyMiddleware(thunk)
);

export default store
```

index.js

```
export * from './actions/blog'
```

I am trying to fetch data using react-redux but API is not hitting. I am new to redux and just trying to make a project but API is not hitting using this. I don't know what I am missing I have also provided provider store in index.js. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I assume `dispatch(fetchBlogRequest())` is not hitting the store either (is that section of code getting called at all?)? Also, since you're new to Redux, I'll suggest you to a) consider using `useSelector` and `useDispatch` instead of map functions, it makes the code more concise and cleaner. b) look into Redux Toolkit, to save you lots of Redux pains.

Comment: Are there any errors? The component does not show anything that would prevent it from dispatching the action, maybe you forgot to Provider or thunk middleware?

Comment: there is no error in console

Answer (score 0):

the `thunk` you made `fetchBlog` should return an async function(a.k.a  a function that return a promise)

you just missed the `return`

```js
function fetchBlog(){
   return function(dispatch){

     dispatch(someAction());

     return axios.get()
            .then(() => {
                dispatch(setAction());
            })
            .catch(error => {
                dispatch(onErrorAction());
            });
   }
}
```

or you can use async/await functions

```js
function fetchBlog(){
    return async (dispatch) => {
       try{
         dispatch(someAction());

         const res = await axios.get();

         dispatch(setAction({ res }));

       }catch(error){

         dispatch(onErrorAction());
       }
    }
}
```

add to that in dispatch to props function you don't need to call it with dispatch because the `thunk-middleware` understand action as function and it go execute it, so you just need to have a reference to the `thunk` itself and you are ready

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
 return {
    fetchBlog: fetchBlog
 }
}
```

or better, just use an object

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    fetchBlog: fetchBlog
}
```

or you can

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    fetchBlog
}
```

which is even simpler

Comment: I found that you are dispatching inside the map to dispatch function so I updated the answer for you ;)